# How to get while loop to get updated in python

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib, gmail-imap

I am using a while loop in python in a project and it's not getting any updates and I have to turn it off and on again. Is there a way to make it update?

Here's the code:

```py
import imaplib
username ="example@gmail.com"
app_password= "example"
gmail_host= 'imap.gmail.com'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(gmail_host)
mail.login(username, app_password)
mail.select()
_, selected_mails = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
while True:
    print({len(selected_mails[0].split())})
```

Output:

```py
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
{19}
...
```

So the output is {19} meaning there are currently 19 emails in my inbox, but when I send one to myself it doesn't update to {20}.

How to get it to update(with the current code)?

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the command inside the while loop

```py
import imaplib
username ="example@gmail.com"
app_password= "example"
gmail_host= 'imap.gmail.com'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(gmail_host)
mail.login(username, app_password)
mail.select()
_, selected_mails = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
while True:
    _, selected_mails = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    print({len(selected_mails[0].split())})
```

Comment: There's literally no difference? did you even test this? its still the same output but slower theres no change

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```py
import imaplib
username ="example@gmail.com"
app_password= "example"
gmail_host= 'imap.gmail.com'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(gmail_host)
mail.login(username, app_password)
while True:
    mail.select()
    _, selected_mails = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    print({len(selected_mails[0].split())})
```